# How to convert *multipart.FileHeader file type to *os.File in golang

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I want to stream multipart file directly to AWSS3 instead of saving file to disk at first. Receiving file of type *multipart.FileHeader in my golang REST API. Now I want to stream this to AWSS3, using [s3manager](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager) upload method where it's required to pass *bytes.Reader in body param. I have seen an example of [uploading file to AWSS3](https://www.nicolasmerouze.com/file-upload-web-service-golang-s3-aws/), written in a way that opening a file **os.Open("filepath")** of type *os.File from disk,getting *bytes.Reader out of it and passing to AWSS3. Now I am struggling to convert this *multipart.FileHeader to *os.File.

Comment: Update. Did some experiments. Now I need to convert multipart.File to os.File

Comment: Do you want an `*os.File` or really an `io.Reader`? The file is only for a file that is physically on disk, but you're also saying that you don't want the file to be on disk?

Comment: Yes, I want io.Reader exactly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call [Open](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#FileHeader.Open) on the `multipart.FileHeader`. It will return a `multipart.File` which will provide a reader to the file (which will be held in memory).

Comment: To add a little more `ParseMultipartForm` will let you control when to have the file in memory, and when they are written to temp. From the docs: a total of maxMemory bytes of its file parts are stored in memory, with the remainder stored on disk in temporary files.

Comment: how can avoid writing to disk(temp) and again taking from it?

Comment: @RaviTejaBathula if you really need an *os.File, you need to write a file somewhere. However, there should be no reason to really require an *os.File.

Comment: @RaviTejaBathula if you want to prevent the files from hitting disk at all, you have two options. (1) set `maxMemory` to a sufficiently large value that it can hold the files in memory (you can use other parts of the `http` package to limit the size of the incoming request). (2) use `*http.Request.MultiPartReader` to access the part's directly.

Comment: @djd I succeeded. I turned incoming file data to bytes and passed to bytes.NewReader() which gave me io.Reader. Thank you for your time. I will optimize code with your idea now.

Comment: @RTBathula I have the same problem. Can you please provide the exact code to turn file into bytes and then passed to bytes.NewReader()?

Comment: Pls share a working code. The words are meaningless without any example code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multipart.File, then you can use next solution:

```golang
file, ok := multipartFile.(*os.File)
if !ok {
    responseError(w, errors.New("invalid file", errors.InvalidArguments))
    return
}
```